# trouble with a tutorial

Tags: android, android-camera

Im trying this tutorial: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482/1954  but there seems to be a problem with the line that says:

```
catch (Throwable ){ }
```

it's spitting an error:

`Syntax error on token "Throwable", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`

The code:

```
        package com.ARtest;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Camera;
        import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
        import android.view.SurfaceView;

        public class CustomCameraView extends SurfaceView
        {
            Camera camera;
            SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
            SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderListener = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera=Camera.open();
        try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        }
        catch (Throwable ){ }
        }
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height)
        {
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        }
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
        {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        }
        };
    //constructor
    public CustomCameraView(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx);
        previewHolder = this.getHolder();
        previewHolder.setType
        (SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderListener);
    }


};
```

Answer (score 2):

Throwable should have a name after, since it is an object. Just change "Throwable" to something like "Throwable e." 
VariableDeclaratorId means an object is unnamed, just like how you wouldn't instantiate a String as

```
private String = "this will not work";
```

To your second question, classes don't require ;'s at the end of them. Typically if there is a closing bracket, you don't need a ; after it.

Tough one to fix! You probably pasted this into eclipse, and it automatically imported graphics.camera. Change that import to hardware.camera, and try it then. Also, change

```
params.setPreviewSize(w, h);
```

to

```
params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
```

Also add the import

```
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
```

Comment: UHG.. this file is all messed up.. i hate to be a helpless donk, but can you show me how the code should read?

Comment: now i am having a syntax issue with this segmant..  i think i picked a bad tutorial
'code'